# Access a html tag in object tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, object

I am working on angular and I want to access the textarea in my object tag.

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://webpage.com">
</object>
```

Imagen that the url has the following:

```
<textarea name="here"></textarea>
```

I trye to find it through the console with:

```
window[0].document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0]
```

But I get Error: Permission denied to access property "document"

Comment: in angular you can create directive and bind html elements into it. you can try that.

Comment: You're not allowed to access the DOM on that page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: This shoudl work var text=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

Comment: @Geeky — No, it shouldn't. The textarea isn't in the current document.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas — Angular doesn't have any magic that violates the same origin policy.

Comment: @Roberrrt — "You're not allowed to access the DOM on that page." is true, but your link doesn't apply.

Comment: @Quentin Oh, ment this one yes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: @Roberrrt — No, that's even less relevant. I think you're looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @Quentin I should seriously take the day off.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, if I find someway to access the content I will come by again.